# Not able to add any subviews (buttons, labels) programatically using XCode 7.0 with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setTitle:@"Test Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

After the app I didn't see the button on View

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you're setting up your View Controller? Are you using a .xib or .storyboard? If so, have you set the View Controller class in IB?

Comment: where did u put the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame of button .

```
btn.frame  =  CGRectMake(x,y,with,height);
```

Comment: I didn't see the button on view even after setting the frames like below 
    
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 45)];
    [btn setTitle:@"Test Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

Comment: ok then use ..[self.View bringSubviewToFront:btn];
[btn setNeedsDisplay]; hope it help you ...

Comment: actual thing is, the button is adding on the view but by default button taking the title color as white.

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame of `UIButton *btn` after that you can see it